# Chat behaves/looks strange in Chrome on a Linux box

Tags: support, chat

Here, on my Ubuntu 64bit with Chrome the chat does look very different from what I was used to see for a long time.

- the right info-bar with the list of online users and the starred comments is completely gone.
- on the bottom I have only a *send* button where there should be and *upload* button too
- most unpleasant thing is, that I get a line-break when hitting enter. I have to click on send with the mouse!

Can someone give me a hand here?

[image]

Comment: This looks like the mobile view. You could try to get the normal view using the menu button bottom left. Select 'Full Site' from the menu.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, thanks! Who would do something like that to me? I didn't press the "Full Site" button since I thought it is something else. Can you post this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to solve?**
This looks like the mobile view. You could try to get the normal view using the menu button bottom left as shown on your picture. Select 'Full Site' from the menu.

The 'full site' switch may also be present in the form of link as in the following picture.
[image]

**How did it get this way?**
At the bottom of a normal screen is a link to the mobile view. You must have clicked on it by accident.

[image]